# OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException when passing BinaryLocation

Tags: selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to create an instance of OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver (v81 with Selenium 4.0.0-alpha05) and am using the [constructor-overload](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/) that gets an instance of [ChromeOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions.htm). The only option that I set is [BinaryLocation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_BinaryLocation.htm), its value is "C:\git\Selenium\Drivers\ChromeDriver81\Win\chromedriver.exe" and that file exists.

However, I do get this:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist 
in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable.
The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.    

   bei OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl)    
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()   
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
```

Have I misunderstood something or is there a bug somewhere in the webdriver-beta oder ChromeDrv?

**P.S:** it also happens with WebDriver 3.1 and Firefox (geckodriver73) when setting [options](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxOptions.htm).[BrowserExecutableLocation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxOptions_BrowserExecutableLocation.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it had misunderstood the purpose of the BinaryLocation and BrowserExecutableLocation properties. Those properties are used to describe the location of the *browser*. The location of the *driver* executable is specified in the overload of CreateDefaulfService() that takes a string, indicating the path to the driver.  I needed to instantiate [ChromeDriverService](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService.htm) and pass that instance in the constructor of the ChromeDriver.